# "PayPal gateway has rejected request" in Magento and Paypal

Tags: magento, paypal

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. The transaction id is not valid (#10004: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).

This error has popped up all of a sudden. It used to work perfectly fine. This error occurs while trying to invoice an order in Magento backend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was an issue with PayPal this morning. It should all be working again now (our store is) https://www.x.com/content/resolved-major-impact-express-checkout-paypal-apis-virtual-terminal-and-website-payments-pro

Answer (score 0):

That could be due to wrong currency.

Please check this:
https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes